# angular: can't set initial value to input box

Tags: angularjs

for my angular i have the following:

this is the html

```
<div ng-app='mainApp' ng-controller='myControl'>
   <mydirective datas="datas"></mydirective>
</div>
```

js file

```
var mainApp=angular.module('mainApp',[])
.controller('myControl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('./myjson.json').success(function(fdatas){
         $scope.datas=fdatas;
    });
}])
.directive('mydirective',function(){
     return{
       restrict:'E',
       scope:{
          datas:'='
       },
       template:"<input type='text' ng-model='inputvar'/>",
       controller:function($scope,window){
         $scope.inputvar=$scope.datas[0].name;
       }
     }
});
```

json file

```
[{ name:'test'},{name:'test2'}]
```

for some reason when i checked the debug console, it comes undefined and initial value can't be set. any idea?

thank you

Comment: Try adding `$scope.inputvar = "Hello World";` in your controller.

Comment: i tried and it works, but not with the data i want.

Comment: What exactly did you want the initial value to be, what did you set it to be and what did it show?

Comment: delcare `$scope.datas` before `$http` like this `$scope.datas=[]`

Comment: do you see any error in the console?

Comment: I did see an error: undefined and also an 'r' in the debug console of safari

Comment: something isn't right here; I don't think your sample code is really representative of the scenario you are trying to solve.  Firstly, it doesn't really make sense to be passing an array of items to a directive that is only going to use the first element.  Secondly, your array of objects only has `name` properties, but you are trying to bind to a `city` property in the directive.  Is that just bad sample data?

Comment: Also, `$http` is async, so when the directive is first populated, the `datas` value may not be returned from the call yet, and would definitely report undefined.

Comment: @claies sorry, it was name. as for the datas, i think that's why i'm using an isolated scope '='

Comment: you would definitely need to define `$scope.datas=[]` inside `myControl` else it will be undefined when the directive is initialized, and the directive won't know when something is added.  Even then, `$scope.datas[0]` is going to be undefined when the directive's controller is instantiated.... You will probably need to use `ng-if="datas"` on the directive to ensure that it's not initialized before you have data it can use.  The async nature of `$http` is not your friend here.

Comment: the isolated scope doesn't have anything to do with the fact that there is no data to pass into that scope at the time you are requesting it (the directive controller instantiation).  Using an isolate scope is to ensure that if you use multiple copies of the same directive on the same page, each copy has it's own data instead of them all sharing the same data.

Comment: @Claies thanks!, i'll give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to declare the model in the controller... something like:

```
var mainApp=angular.module('mainApp',[])
    .controller('myControl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
        $scope.inputvar = "Hello World";
        $http.get('./myjson.json').success(function(fdatas){
            $scope.datas=fdatas;
    });
}])
```

Comment: thanks @andand, i'm gonna be working with this inputvar inside the directive, is that the only way to set the initial value properly?

Comment: There are other ways... using a service to communicate between the controller and directive comes to mind; this allows you to abstract away some of the functionality from both the directive and the controller.  However, the examples in the documentation at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive uses this pattern frequently... initialize the model in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html ng-app=''>
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script></head>
  <body ng-init='var=10'>
    <input type='text' ng-model='var'/>
 </body></html>
```